# WordPress Admin Notice Dismissal

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm currently building a WordPress Plugin, and in this plugin I need a WordPress admin notification.  I was able to create the admin notification, however when I dismiss it, on the next reload of the page it shows up again.  How do I get this to not display once a user has dismissed it?

```
function admin_notice_eagle_daily() {
$displayVar = '<b>EAGLE Display Reminder:</b>'; ?>
<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
    <p><?php _e($displayVar, 'sample-eagle-text-domain'); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
```

}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'admin_notice_daily' );

Comment: Could you share some code examples? Please also read the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :-)

Comment: Edited and updated